# Toolbox disappeared after installing charts for ASP.NET in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, charts, toolbox

Downloaded charts from [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) site. I installed 1,2 and 3 parts. Now the toolbox does not show any control. There is an additinal tab that appears next to toolbox and it has no name. How to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the toolbox area, choose reset. Restart Visual studio. Start a new project. The controls appears.